# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-8

I just don't know what's wrong with my code and why it produces this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `cars` inner join `car_books` on `car_books`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id` order by `created_at` desc)

Here's my code:

```
public function carBook()
{
    $car_books = Car::join('car_books','car_books.car_id','=','cars.id')->latest()->get();
    return view('admin.car_book',compact('car_books'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to order by `cars.created_at` or `car_books.created_at`.

Both tables have `created_at` column, so it is ambiguous.

Comment: i have changed my code like this: public function carBook()
    {
        $car_books = Car::join('car_books','car_books.car_id','=','cars.id')->orderBy('car_books.created_at', 'desc')->latest()->get();
        return view('admin.car_book',compact('car_books'));
    }  but then i get this error :    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `cars` inner join `car_books` on `car_books`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id` order by `car_books`.`created_at` desc, `created_at` desc)

Comment: You shouldn`t use latest(). Just try to use ->limit(1)->get()

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is a `created_at` field in both the `cars` and `car_books` table. You need to specify exactly which of those you want to use within the `order by` clause. So either:

```sql
order by cars.created_at desc
```

Or:

```sql
order by car_books.created_at desc
```

Comment: i have changed my code like this:  public function carBook() { $car_books = Car::join('car_books','car_books.car_id','=','cars.id')->orderBy('car_books.created_at', 'desc')->latest()->get(); return view('admin.car_book',compact('car_books')); }                                                 
but then i get this error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from cars inner join car_books on car_books.car_id = cars.id order by car_books.created_at desc, created_at desc)

Comment: Remove `latest()`